# Не работает copy() при запуске скрипта по крону

Tags: php, cron

Здравствуйте.
Переливаю данные со старого сайта, к которому нет админского доступа, на новый. Не суть важно. 
Есть php-скрипт, в котором есть вот такой кусок

```
copy("путь_к_файлу_на_старом_сайте/файл.jpg","путь_к_файлу_на_новом_сайте/файл.jpg");
```

Если скрипт запускается вручную, то всё срабатывает нормально, файл копируется. Но если этот же самый скрипт запускаю по cron, не копируется.

В чём может быть трабла, куда копать? Спасибо!

Comment: Сделайте вывод ошибок с записью в лог-файл, cron вообще запускается?

Comment: @DaemonHK да, крон запускается, скрипт по крону срабатывает, не срабатывает только copy

Comment: 1. Вручную и cron'ом скрипт запускается под разными пользователями.
2. Используются пути относительно текущего каталога и текущие каталоги разные при запуске вручную и под cron'ом.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятней всего что-то с правами доступа к папка. Проверьте есть ли права, т.к. крон запускается под другим юзером( ну это не точно).

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/225422)

Comment: Тем не менее, это помогло автору.

Answer (score 0):

Действительно, оказалось, что cron запускает скрипт под другим юзером, и необходимо указывать иной путь до создаваемого файла.
В моём случае помогло вот так

```
$func_dir = dirname(__FILE__).'/imgs'; //это путь до директории, в которую копируются файлы, а затем уже copy
```